# How to download kerberos version 4 Message Exchange?

Tags: python, kerberos

Need to use kerberos version 4 Message Exchange for chat program so How to download kerberos version 4.

Comment: Kerberos 4 is dead, go 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which system are you using? kerberos 4.0 is distributed only as a Windows Installer MSI file as far as I know. You can find the installer [here](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/index.html)